# How To Select all the Duplicate Records in a single table in SQl

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to select all the duplicate records in a single column from single table. i have used the following code .but in that i am able to get only one duplicate record. the code is like below

```
SELECT Datetime COUNT(*)FROM  users GROUP BY Datetime HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

But i want result like below table

```
TableName:MyTable
DateTime
04/16/2015
04/16/2015
04/16/2015
04/16/2015
```

but my query giving like below.

```
DateTime
 04/16/2015 count(4)
```

Please help me in this

Answer (score 3):

`Join` back to the original data;

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT Datetime
      FROM users
      GROUP BY Datetime
      HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
     ) d
     ON u.Datetime = d.Datetime;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Datetime from Users
where Datetime in 
          (SELECT Datetime FROM  users GROUP BY Datetime HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1)
```